# Download a secure file to repo code in Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am creating a Pipeline to automatically build and release a flutter app. On my machine the `flutter build appbundle --release` works just fine and also signs the app correctly. I reference a key and a properties file, which I both don't want to upload into the repo, but instead use the `Library > Secure Files`.

How can I either download these files onto my Agent to a specific position, or use the downloaded file path in my `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can utilize "Download Secure File task" to download from the library on to your agent.

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'secureFile'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: secureFile
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: I already found this task, but this task downloads the file somewhere onto my agent machine. But I need it in a specific location, so that I can use this location in my build.gradle

Comment: Yes, the task downloads the file under $(Agent.TempDirectory) on your agent machine and you can use copyFiles task to copy it to your target location which can reference in your properties file.

Comment: Thanks! This did in fact work after I changed the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) to $(Build.SourcesDirectory), since I need it in relation to my code.

Comment: Oh great. Glad that helped :)

Comment: This seems somewhat dangerous if the file is sensitive, should it really be stored in a artifact?

Answer (score -1):

MS Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-secure-file-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops

```
     - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
        name: gradlePropertyOverrides
        inputs:
          secureFile: 'filename.filenameExtension'

     - task: Gradle@2
        inputs:
          gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
          options: -PpropertyOverridePath=$(gradlePropertyOverrides.secureFilePath)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).